# Limit of integration when substitution $t = x^{-1}$

Tags: integration

> Using substitution $t = x^{-1}$,
>   Solve
>   $\int_a^b {\dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}dt}$, when $0<a<b$

I am confused to wheter I should change order of the new limit $\dfrac 1 a$ and $\dfrac 1 b$ since $0<a<b$ ?

New integration formed will have smaller value as upper bound.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: No you should not change the order of limits. Also, there is no rule against integrating from a larger value to a smaller one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting $t=\frac{1}{u}$ we have:
$$ I(a,b)= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{(t-a)(b-t)}}=\int_{\frac{1}{b}}^{\frac{1}{a}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-ua)(ub-1)}}\tag{1}$$
and by setting $u=\frac{1}{b}+v\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)$ we get:
$$ I(a,b) = \left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{\sqrt{\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}v(1-v)}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{ab}}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: So which one of you is correct? Arpan says I should not change the order of the limits and you did here. For part (2) I used substitution $x=\dfrac {1}{b} \cos^2 \theta + \dfrac {1}{a} \sin^2 \theta$

Comment: @zcahfg2: to write $\int_{c}^{d}f(x)\,dx$ or $-\int_{d}^{c}f(x)\,dx$ is just a matter of taste, it is legit.